# Is streaming audio from my DAW to Discord possible with a discord bot?

Tags: node.js, discord, bots, audio-streaming, ableton-live

I found out the other day that discord bots had the ability to play audio in stereo which is not possible with a regular discord account. Maybe it could be possible to stream Ableton Live's audio output to a node.js server for a bot to play back in a Discord channel.

I found this plugin : https://listento.audiomovers.com/ which is a good starting point.

This page shows exemples of audio playback code but not live streaming methods https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/PlayInterface?scrollTo=play

The idea is to live stream audio without the delay that could be caused by video with a soft like OBS. And Discord would be a great platform for this as people would be able to react and make music together.

I need help with the structure of all this. Do you think this is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/
and it's free alternative https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases

If you run your discord bot locally then you can just set Ableton's output to be an input for the bot using one of the above.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, You can use Asio Link Pro Tool The developer gives it out for free and I use it all the time, especially when chaining audio interfaces together to get more inputs. Works great, you can check out a video with Mr. Different TV on Youtube to understand it.

https://give.academy/downloads/2018/03/03/ODeusASIOLinkPro/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emRZxa0pqbs

Unlimited inputs and outputs (>:o)